# Embed basic WebKit + V8 in my app

Tags: webkit, embed, v8, chromium, embedded-browser

I want a very basic HTML/CSS/JS renderer embedded in my app using WebKit and preferably V8. All I need is to always render one page and possibly make network and local requests (load JSON/msgpack). I don't need prefetch, tabs, omnibox, profiles and other chromium features, but from what I see looking at CEF is that it embeds a full featured chromium. Are there any other solutions?